# Softlayer Post ProvisiopostInstallScriptUri

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

After VM provisioning in Softlayer using Softlayer cli or web portal, post provisioning script does not get downloaded into VM. Is there a debug flag that can be turned on to troubleshoot downloading post provisioning script into VM?

c:/PostScript folder gets created on the VM ithBuildINI, postscript and wget files only.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

First verify that URL of postscript already exists, if your postscript was successfully downloaded in another environment I recommend to submit a ticket in order to review it.

There is no way to know when download fails, it is handled by the server during VM provisioning.

There are two options to repeat the download process:

**a) By executing the method [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::executeRemoteScript](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/executeRemoteScript)**

This returns NULL when success and an exception like this if fails:

```
Script download failed. Could not confirm file downloaded correctly.
```

The script is directly downloaded in unit C, and also there is a log file called postInstallScript_Download.txt. 
Use this method after VSI provisioning(when it is ON). You can use following example in python to test this method.

```py
"""
Download and run remote script from uri on virtual guests.
This returns NULL when success and an exception like this if fails:
    "Script download failed. Could not confirm file downloaded correctly."
See below for more details.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/executeRemoteScript

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# The virtual guest ID.
guestId = 31003555

# Declares a new API service object.
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
virtualGuestService = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest']

# URL where is hosted the script you want to download.
uri = "http://www.example.com/test_container/folder/startNotepad.cmd"

try:
    result = virtualGuestService.executeRemoteScript(uri, id=guestId)
    print("File was downloaded!!")
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Error: %s, %s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

Change **31003555** and **http://www.example.com/test_container/folder/startNotepad.cmd** with your own data.

**b) By reloading the OS through web portal or cli**

I recommend to use the web portal, you need only to set the postscript url and the service will automatically set previous configurations like operating system, firewall, etc.

Take account that reload will format the primary disk and will reconfigure the computing instance to the specifications on record. On this case, there is also no way to know when download process fails.

Here you can find information about how to made a reload and add a post-script:
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/perform-os-reload
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/os-reloads

Also you can review:
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/add-custom-provisioning-script
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/add-provisioning-script
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faq/what-difference-between-using-http-or-https-url-my-provisioning-script

I hope this help you.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks Albert for feedback. Script is available and can be downloaded into VM manually using wget. The question is, is there a debug flag in python api or a log to look at for script download error?

Comment: Hi Behzad, there is no way to know if download fails after VSI provisioning (when VSI is ordered) or during OS reload. You can try by using the method "executeRemoteScript". I upload my answer, please see above.

Comment: Thank you Albert for your help. Will test by adding above virtualGuestService.executeRemoteScript.

Comment: I added this code:                                                                                          virtualGuestService = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest']
 # URL where is hosted the script you want to download.
 uri = "https://s3wbld700/create-mdtrecordauto.cmd"
 try:
  result = virtualGuestService.executeRemoteScript(uri, id=vg_id)
  print("File was downloaded!!")
 except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
  print("Error: %s, %s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
exit(1)

Comment: The return message is:                                                                                                                    The return code msg is:                                                                                                              Running script on VM ID: 31794501
Error: SoftLayer_Exception_Notification_HookFailure, Script download failed. Could not confirm file downloaded correctly.                                                                                                    Not finding any hit how to debug this. Any idea?

Comment: You need to put a complete URL in uri parameter, I mean it need to start from http or https, and it should contain the domain. eg. http://www.test.com. Verify that you can download the file using any browser

Comment: The uri should contain the hostname,domain,container, and path to file.Verify that you can download the file using any browser.